# Sorting and Deleting a 1-to-Many relatiionship in SQLALCHEMY and flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am working a CRUD flask project that works with a 1-to-many relationship. The end result looks like this, [Flask Webform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1bl8.png).  However when I submit the form for the Update route, it returns to the home page and displays this. [Webform After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ65e.png).

Here is my [DB model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUCor.png)

def update(id):

```
frank = Frankendama.query.get(id)
form = FrankForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    
    frank.title=form.title.data
    frank.description=form.description.data
    frank.tama=form.tama.data
    frank.sarado=form.sarado.data
    frank.sword=form.sword.data
    frank.string=form.string.data
    frank.bearing=form.bearing.data
            
    db.session.add(frank)  
    db.session.commit()

    comps = form.companies.data
    comps_used = comps.split(",")

    all_comps = Company.query.all().filter_by(Company.frankendama_id == id) #Error here

    for entry in all_comps:
        if entry.frankendama_id == id:
            db.session.delete(entry)

    for i in range(0, len(comps_used)):

        new_entry = comps_used[i]
        new_comp = Company(name=new_entry, frankendama_id=id)

        db.session.add(new_comp)
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for("home"))

else:

    return render_template("create.html", form=form)
```

I am trying to find a query for the Companies table that sorts for all rows with the foreign key 'frankendama_id' that is same to the main tables id. That way i can delete them and then re add them.

When i try using filter() or filter_by() i get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`

I am really stumped, any suggestions are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move filter_by in front of .all()

```
all_comps = Company.query.filter_by(frankendama_id = id).all()
```

edit 1:
Also you can remove 'Company.' when using filter_by and you only need a single equals sign

Comment: I also removed the: if entry.frankendama_id == id: from the for loop as i realised the condition was already being done. Thank you so much!